# How to only keep the first unique regex matches?

Tags: javascript, regex

Lets start with what I have.
I'm working with a system that gathers logs from many nodes.
Short messages are displayed on a web page with a link to some more information about a particular node.
There are anywhere from a few hundred to a few thousand rows to look over.

I've created a heavily reduced example at the bottom that you can run.

Terms explained:
node id = e.g. "c01m01" this would indicate one node, "c01m02", "c02m01" would be two other nodes.
short message example: "error c01m01 unable to start" or "warn c03m01 unable to parse business report"

What I want is to create a regex that only keeps the first unique match, by node identification in this particular case.

I'm not interested in things that contain "business" or "management", since that isn't working correctly yet.

So I want messages containing those words removed in the matching.
When that is done I want the top-most row for each unique node reference as a match, but not anything for that node that is further down the list.

As for my example, the bold nodes are what want to uniquly match:

> verbose **c01m01** startup ok
>
> warn *c02m02* unable to parse business report
>
> verbose c01m01 starting
>
> warn **c02m02** miss-configured
>
> verbose c02m02 startup ok
>
> verbose c02m02 starting
>
> verbose **c03m05** starting

Be aware of the *c02m02* on the second line, I do **not** want that matched, even though it's the top-most messages from that node.

Willing to use **es2018** with lookbehind support, if that helps.
If not already enabled it can be enabled in most chrome based browsers with `chrome://flags/#enable-javascript-harmony` though it's still experimental and not considered stable yet.

I've tried expressions such as `/(?<!\A[\S\s]*?\1[\S\s]*?\G)( c\d{2}m\d{2} )(?!.*(business|management))/ig` and varieties there of, without any success. Not sure if `\A` or `\G` are usable in this flavor of regex, but I've tried a whole bunch of others expressions not including either of them.
The closest I've come, is to match the last entry for each node (close to the **opposite** of what i want) with `/( c\d{2}m\d{2} )(?![\s\S]*\1)/ig`

I'm a beginner on regex and might be missing something trivial, but so far my internet research on the matter haven't turned up with anything either.
Is what I want to achieve simply not possible with regex, or js-regex in particular?

Any help in the matter is much appreciated, and a detailed explanation even more so.

```js
function regex_mod_fn() {
  let msgRows = document.getElementsByName('entry');

  function show_all() {
    for (let i = 0; i < msgRows.length; i++) {
      msgRows[i].style.display = document.defaultRowDisplay;
    }
  }

  // Validation needs more work.
  let validInput = /^\/.+\/\S*$/;
  let re_input = document.getElementById('regex_input');
  let re_raw = re_input.value;
  if (!validInput.test(re_raw)) {
    re_input.style.borderColor = !!(re_raw.length) ? 'red' : '';
    show_all();
    return;
  }
  re_input.style.borderColor = '';

  // Construct the regex object
  let re_str = re_raw.substr(1, re_raw.lastIndexOf('/') - 1);
  let re_flags = re_raw.substr(re_raw.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
  let re = undefined;
  try {
    if (re_flags === '')
      re = new RegExp(re_str);
    else
      re = new RegExp(re_str, re_flags);
  } catch (e) {
    re_input.style.borderColor = 'red';
    console.error(e);
    return;
  }

  const msgList = document.msgList;

  let result = null;

  // Save the number of rows and character position for each new line.
  let newLineIndex = [];
  let reNewLine = /\n/g;
  while ((result = reNewLine.exec(msgList)) !== null) {
    newLineIndex.push(reNewLine.lastIndex);
  }

  // Find the matches and save the row index
  let matchRow = [];
  while ((result = re.exec(msgList)) !== null) {
    for (let i = 0; i < newLineIndex.length; i++) {
      if (result.index < newLineIndex[i]) {
        matchRow.push(i);
        break;
      }
    }

    if (!re.global) {
      break;
    }
  }

  // Sort and remove duplicates
  matchRow = matchRow.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a - b;
  }).filter((x, i, a) => !i || x != a[i - 1]);

  // Show/hide rows, based on if they match the regex
  let idx = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < msgRows.length; i++) {
    let row = msgRows[i];
    if (matchRow[idx] === i) {
      row.style.display = document.defaultRowDisplay;
      idx++;
    } else {
      row.style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
}

function init() {
  document.defaultRowDisplay = document.getElementsByName('entry')[0].style.display;
  document.msgList = '';

  let msgRows = document.getElementsByName('entry');
  for (let i = 0; i < msgRows.length; i++) {
    let msg = msgRows[i].firstElementChild.innerHTML;
    document.msgList += msg + '\n';
  }
  regex_input.addEventListener('input', regex_mod_fn);
}

init();
```

```html
<input id="regex_input" type="text" size=50 placeholder="regex" />
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Message</th>
      <th>Link</th>
      <th>Log Size</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr name="entry">
      <td>verbose c01m01 startup ok</td>
      <td><a href="http://www.example.com">details</a></td>
      <td>1.14 KB</td>
    </tr>
    <tr name="entry">
      <td>warn c02m02 unable to parse business report</td>
      <td><a href="http://www.example.com">details</a></td>
      <td>4.30 MB</td>
    </tr>
    <tr name="entry">
      <td>verbose c01m01 starting</td>
      <td><a href="http://www.example.com">details</a></td>
      <td>753.78 KB</td>
    </tr>
    <tr name="entry">
      <td>warn c02m02 miss-configured</td>
      <td><a href="http://www.example.com">details</a></td>
      <td>1.14 KB</td>
    </tr>
    <tr name="entry">
      <td>verbose c02m02 startup ok</td>
      <td><a href="http://www.example.com">details</a></td>
      <td>4.30 MB</td>
    </tr>
    <tr name="entry">
      <td>verbose c02m02 starting</td>
      <td><a href="http://www.example.com">details</a></td>
      <td>753.78 KB</td>
    </tr>
    <tr name="entry">
      <td>verbose c03m05 starting</td>
      <td><a href="http://www.example.com">details</a></td>
      <td>1.14 KB</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just get all the nodes and then filter out the duplicates?

Comment: I'm open to suggestions. As it is the regex field is for more things than just this particular example. To clarify, I'm not alone in using this tool, and others most likely want to do matching in some other way. So if I'm to suggest a change to the tool, it should work for the use-cases it does today. The code I provided here is just a quick hack I did to showcase the principal function behind the tool that's actually used. Anyhow, thanks for the feedback, I'll keep that in mind and try to come up with a solution where that might be doable. Never the less, the question is still open.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for. The trick is to build up a list of previously matched nodes. Your starting regex was pretty close, the only part you were missing was trying to solve it *completely* with regex. Creating a new regex pattern each time based on previous matches will get you the first occurence of each node (with the obvious exception of lines containing *business* and *management*, as you requested).

```js
const str = `
verbose c01m01 startup ok

warn c02m02 unable to parse business report

verbose c01m01 starting

warn c02m02 miss-configured

verbose c02m02 startup ok

verbose c02m02 starting

verbose c03m05 starting
`;

const previousNodes = [];
const nodeRegexString = '(c\\d{2}m\\d{2})';
const exclusions = ['business', 'management'];

const returnUniqueNodes = str =>
    str.split('\n').filter(line => {
        const regex = new RegExp(
            `.*${previousNodes.length
                ? `(?!.*${previousNodes.join('|')})`
                : ''}${nodeRegexString}${exclusions.length
                ? `(?!.*${exclusions.join('.*|')})`
                : ''}.*`,
            'im'
        );

        if (regex.test(line)) {
            previousNodes.push(line.match(new RegExp(nodeRegexString))[0]);
            return line;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });

console.log(returnUniqueNodes(str));
```

https://repl.it/@ryanpcmcquen/returnUniqueNodes

Comment: @Ale, any questions?

Comment: It looks like the proposed snippet in the comments from the question. Does this mean that it is not possible to solve with regex?

Comment: @Ale, I don't see the comment you mentioned. But it is possible to solve with regex, as long as you allow that regex to morph while you are doing the matching.

Comment: My bad, I meant your proposed idea for a solution with js instead of _only_ regex. I don't know what you mean by letting the regex morph while matching. Do you mean it's **necessary** to save previous results outside the regex, like you've done in your example?

Comment: @Ale, yes, as far as I can tell.

Comment: okay, thank you, do you know why? So far I've found no references. I'll do a bit more digging into why it's not possible, to have something more tangible. So if someone asks me why in the future, I'll have an answer. If no one beats me to it I'll add the info and accept the best answer available at that time.

Comment: @Ale, the main reason, as far as I can tell, is that you are discarding matches that are programatically/syntactically the same (or at least similar). Regex doesn't work with some kind of backtracing history (to my knowledge).